# use Malgun Gothic system font in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts

For an international project I need to display korean letters/signs inside Flash.
Because most of the fonts that include the "asian unicode range" are too big to embed completely into the swf, I'm sticking with `Malgun Gothic` as a font. It's pre-installed on Windows (7 at least) so no need to load anything.

With my german Windows7 installation I can just say

```
new TextFormat('Malgun Gothic');
```

and it's displayed correctly but in Korea the font(-name) isn't recognized.
Anyone ever tried this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest loading a different font library for the different languages. This way you can save non-Korean users from the massive download. I have done something similar to this for Chinese using the technique outlined on my [blog here](http://blog.sitedaniel.com/2008/10/fontcontrol-class-external-font-library/)

Comment: thanks for the reply. but it doesn't really help. of course I'm using different fonts in different countries and they only download the one they need. but in no case I want the user to have to download 4-5MB just to display a font that is already installed on the system.

Comment: @pkyeck the only font you can ever count on being installed on the system is the default font. Whatever it is it will always be there anything other then the default font is not reliable.